# Spring RequestMapping: differentiate PathVariable with different types

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there a way to tell Spring to map request to different method by the type of path variable, if they are in the same place of the uri?
For example,

```
@RequestMapping("/path/{foo}")  

@RequestMapping("/path/{id}")
```

if foo is supposed to be string, id is int, is it possible to map correctly instead of looking into the request URI?

Comment: It is not possible to do this without a considerable amount of configuration. Can you give an example of the purpose of doing this?

Comment: People would like to change the format of some api into something like the first one, while I already have something like the second.

Comment: It's not worth the hassle. Change your handler methods instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the spring docs it is possible to use regex for path variables, here's the example from the docs:

```
@RequestMapping("/spring-web/{symbolicName:[a-z-]+}-{version:\\d\\.\\d\\.\\d}{extension:\\.[a-z]+}")
  public void handle(@PathVariable String version, @PathVariable String extension) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

(example taken from http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-patterns )

Judging from that, it should be possible to write something like this for your situation:

```
@RequestMapping("/path/{foo:[a-z]+}")  

@RequestMapping("/path/{id:[0-9]+}")
```

Comment: Use `@RequestMapping("/path/{foo:[A-Za-z]+}")`, to get also `uppercase` for String.